# Why JavaFX is calling onAction when I press ESC?

Tags: javafx, escaping, submit, keypress

I have a button with onAction="doSomething", which is called when I press ESC?
But why behaviors ESC like Enter?

Answer (score 2):

Because JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 enabled the checkbox for cancel button...

Sorry.